# How to replace a word with new line

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression, newlines

I have a text file with following data and each row ends with `|END|`.

```
T|somthing|something|END|T|something2|something2|END|
```

I am tryig to replace `|END|` with `\n` new line with sed.

```
 sed 's/\|END\|/\n/g' test.txt
```

But it's producing wrong output like below:

```
 T
 |
 s
 o
 m
 e
 ...
```

But what I want is this:

```
T|somthing|something
T|something2|something2
```

I also tried with `tr`. It didn't work either.

Comment: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use this:

```
sed 's/|END|/\n/g' test.txt
```

What you attempted doesn't work because sed uses [basic regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended), and your sed implementation has a `\|` operator meaning “or” (a common extension to BRE), so what you wrote replaces (empty string or `END` or empty string) by a newline.

Comment: Need to comment out the \ in \n:  sed 's/|END|/\\n/g

Comment: @Baazigar No, what A.B. wrote is correct (for Linux at least, some sed implementations would emit `\n`). The question asks how to replace `|END|` by a newline, not by `\n`.

Comment: The characters for newline are '\n'. The \\n is needed because \ also is an escape character, so if you do only \n, you are saying 'escape this n character'. When you do \\n you are saying 'don't treat this next \ as an escape.'.

Answer (score 8):

The following worked fine for me:

```
$ sed 's/|END|/\
/g' foobar
T|somthing|something
T|something2|something2
```

Notice that I just put a backslash followed by the enter key.

Comment: That's the standard syntax. Using `\n` [as in @A.B.'s answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194051) wouldn't work with some `sed` implementations.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas What sed implementation supports `\|` for alternation in a regexp but not `\n` meaning newline in an `s` replacement?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'\\|END\\|' '{$1=$1}1' OFS='\n' file
T|somthing|something
T|something2|something2
```

- `-F'\\|END\\|'` set field separator to `|END|`
- `OFS='\n'` set ouput field separator to newline
- `$1=$1` cause `awk` reconstruct `$0` with `OFS` as field separator
- `1` is a true value, cause`awk` print the whole input line

Answer (score 3):

Another possibly [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) command and using its `RS` option would be:

```bsh
awk '$1=$1' RS="\|END\|" file
```

Will print those records (based on awk's **R**ecord **S**eparator) which are not empty( has at least one field) to prevent printing empty lines.

Tested on this input:

```
T|somthing|something|END|T|something2|something2|END|
Test|END|
|END|
```

Gives this output:

```
T|somthing|something
T|something2|something2
Test
```

That cleared all empty lines :) If you want to have newlines too, replace `$1=$1` with `$0` in command:

```bsh
awk '$0' RS="\|END\|" file
```

Comment: `$1=$1` condenses sequences of blanks into one space character and returns false if the first field is 0. Doesn't make sense. You probably want `awk 1 RS='\\|END\\|'` or `awk NF RS='\\|END\\|'` or `awk length RS='\\|END\\|'` here. Note that a regexp RS requires gawk or mawk

Answer (score 3):

Another way with `sed` that doesn't print empty lines:

```
sed 's/|END|/\
/g;/^$/!P;D' infile
```

e.g. input:

```
T|one|two|END|T|three|four|END|
T|five|six|END|T|seven|eight|END|
T|nine|ten|END|T|eleven|twelve|END|
```

output:

```
T|one|two
T|three|four
T|five|six
T|seven|eight
T|nine|ten
T|eleven|twelve
```

same thing with `ed`:

```
ed -s infile <<'IN'
1,$j
s/|END|/\
/g
,p
q
IN
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748453/replace-comma-with-newline-in-sed-on-macos) by [Walter Mundt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/197325/walter-mundt), we can achieve this using an [ANSI C quoted string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html)

```
sed $'s/|END|/\\\n/g'

~ $ echo 'T|somthing|something|END|T|something2|something2|END|' | sed 
$'s/|END|/\\\n/g'
T|somthing|something
T|something2|something2

~ $
```

Check out the above here link for other alternatives.

You can use the following syntax as well, I'm not sure if it works on all flavours of Unix/Linux

```
sed 's/|END|/\'$'\n''/g'

~ $ echo 'T|somthing|something|END|T|something2|something2|END|' | sed 
's/|END|/\'$'\n''/g'
T|somthing|something
T|something2|something2

~ $
```

Comment: Working on FreeBSD v10. Actually, only method that worked for me. Thanks you.

Comment: Worked on macos, while the other answers did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a same issue in strict posix shell
I did it in two pass with a unused char

```
cat data.json|tr '§' '?'|sed -e 's/"[^"]":/§&/g'|tr '§' '\n'
```